# Twilio IP Messaging: What is the point of [client handleNotification] in the iOS messaging client API?

Tags: ios, twilio, messaging

Located here:

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/ip-messaging/releases/0.13.6/docs/Classes/TwilioIPMessagingClient.html#//api/name/handleNotification:

I'm building a twilio IP Messaging app and can't deconstruct the use of the function. The docs are cryptic and the example

https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-ios/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=handlenotification

doesn't make it clear either.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `handleNotification` method should be used when your application receives an incoming notification from APNS. It's a convenience function that parses the notification and creates all the relevant SDK objects.

In the demo, you can see that [notifications are received by the AppDelegate](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-ios/blob/b2dbdd7a94283dc8146d25d776d7466902aae13b/Demo-ObjC/AppDelegate.m#L58-L63) (where you can direct different notifications to different parts of your application if you need to), [passed on to the IPMessagingManager here](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-ios/blob/e0d9027574f9ff4eaa0c1cacf2401818a8682e27/Demo-ObjC/IPMessagingManager.m#L90-L93) and finally [passed into the IPMessagingClient via `handleNotification` in the part you pointed out](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-ios/blob/e0d9027574f9ff4eaa0c1cacf2401818a8682e27/Demo-ObjC/IPMessagingManager.m#L108).

Let me know if that helps at all.